# Move UILabel on custom cell when entering editing

Tags: ios

I've got 3 uilabels added to a uitableview cell.  The problem that I am running into is when I swipe to delete, my UILabel on the right side of the cell doesn't move so the delete button and the UILabel are overlapping each other. I've posted some of my code below.

I developed my layout using storyboard, so from what I am reading, frames aren't going to help.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *baseTableCellIdentifier = @"baseCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:baseTableCellIdentifier];

    BaseInfo *infoAtIndex = [[[DataClass getInstance] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    baseName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    baseICAO = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    baseTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:baseName];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:baseICAO];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:baseTime];

    [baseName setText:[infoAtIndex name]];
    [baseICAO setText:[infoAtIndex icao]];



    baseTimeZome = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:[infoAtIndex timeZone]];
    [baseDate setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    [baseDate setTimeZone:baseTimeZome];

    NSString *baseTimeString = [baseDate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [baseTime setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
    [baseTime setText:baseTimeString] ;


    return cell;
}


-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{

    if (editing) {

        //no idea what to put here

    }else{

    }



}
```

Comment: have you tried setting your `UILabel autoresizemask`? If you aren't using AutoLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UITableViewCell` subclass override `setEditing:animated:` and perform there any layout change. As the commenter says, you may not need to do that setting proper values for your label's `autoresizingMask`.

Comment: I used this to fix it.

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    CGPoint frame = baseTime.center;
    
    
    if (editing && !self.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
        frame.x = 200;
        self.baseTime.center = frame;

    } else if (!editing){
        frame.x = 246;
        self.baseTime.center = frame;
    }
    

}

Answer (score 0):

You should create a cell subclass. Then you can implement `setEditing:animated:` to modify the subviews frames.